# How to stop input text event handler from firing in case of pasted text event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

In my example I want two separate event handlers for typed in data and pasted data. The problem that I'm facing is that for every data that I paste the `keyup` event handler also fires. How to stop it?

The code:

```js
$(".inp-txt").on('keyup', function() {
  console.log("Handler for on keyup is called");
});

$(".inp-txt").on('paste', function() {
  console.log("Handler for on paste is called.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="inp-txt">
```

Can you please provide the solution in vanilla JavaScript as well as jQuery?

Comment: try replace `keyup` with `input`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I tried replacing it, still the event handler fires up.

Comment: You cannot stop people pasting with the keyboard, so you'll just have to deal with it by detecting CTRL + V and SHIFT + INS keypresses. Also, you should not be using `bind()` as its deprecated. Change those references to use `on()` instead

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thought i whas creating the answer, when i pressed enter the comment whas there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Keyup even handler, you can check key code and identify if it is for `ctrl + v` and then skip the inner code execution and it will execute only paste event code. This is work around as we cannot bind event for only past and not keyup.

Note: i have put logic to check if control key pressed before v but this will not work if user press control key and then drop idea to paste and try to press v.

```js
var isCtrl = false;
$(".inp-txt").bind('keyup', function(e) {
    //console.log(e.keyCode);
    //console.log(e.ctrlKey);
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
       isCtrl = true;
    } else if(isCtrl && e.keyCode == 17) {
        isCtrl = false;
    } else {
       isCtrl = false;
       console.log("Handler for keyup bind is called");
     }
});

$(".inp-txt").bind('paste', function() {
  console.log("Handler for paste bind is called.");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="inp-txt">
```

Comment: downvoters, at least do some efforts to put reason of down vote

Comment: If you take the time to educate the OP as to why their current code doesn't work and how this helps (now that your edit fixed it) they'd consider it.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar this doesn't work if I only type the letter `v`.

Comment: @KaranDhir, i have put logic for v letter key but this will fail if user just press control key and then do nothing and then try to press v. This will fail in this case only

Comment: happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you.

```
$(".inp-txt").bind('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode != 17)
    console.log("Handler for keyup bind is called");
});

$(".inp-txt").bind('paste', function() {
  console.log("Handler for paste bind is called.");
});
```